# Google chrome new tab

Tags: google-chrome, thumbnails

my website when most visited got position in google chrome 8 snapshot new tab page but the name below it is "free hosting , free" I want my website name there.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the page comes from the below code in the HTML file:

```
<head>
    <title>PUT TITLE HERE</title>
</head>
```

So first edit that file to say what you want.

To refresh google chrome's new tab page open the new tab page and left click each page in turn (Note: right click open in new tab may not refresh the image).